# objects not falling realistically

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I have modeled a screw(like a wood screw) and I want it to fall onto a rigid body plane.  When it falls it hits the plane and has a little bit of movement after that, but mostly stays in the same exact position, which is against all physics...I've pushed a bunch of buttons in the rigid body settings, nothing really helps.  Any suggestions?  Also, where is the option to 'multiply volume by mass'(I don't know if that will help, but I want to try.)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have wrong Rigid body Collision shape, try changing it to mesh:
[image]

Comment: I actually had mesh on, but since you mentioned it, I decided to try a cone, since it is roughly cone shaped and it worked pretty well.  Thanks